# Why is AddComment on SocialCommentManager throwing SPException?

Tags: security, social, collaboration

When I try to add a comment using SocialCommentManager, the AddComment method throws an SPException saying

> "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

I have tried setting AllowUnsafeUpdates to true on the lists parentweb, but that don't work.

Comment: Good question, our OOB Note Board Web Part stopped working suddenly and gives that error in ULS.